# Variable-length argparse argument lists

Tags: python, argparse

I want to have a set of arguments be passed into a script with an equal amount of `inputs` and `outputs` arguments. I know that I can parse along the lines of

```py
inputs, outputs = sys.argv[:halfway], sys.argv[halfway:]
```

taking into account `sys.argv[0]` being the name, but I want the helpful features of `argparse`.

I also know that I can change the code to `parser.add_argument('-i', 'inputs', nargs='+')` so that I can specify my arguments as `python testarg.py -i 1 2 -o 3 4`, but I do not want to use that syntax as there is already a precedent of one-input, one-output `python testarg.py input output` which I would like to keep by making the syntax `python testarg.py inputs[...] outputs[...]`

This is the closest I get

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('inputs', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('outputs', nargs='+')
print(parser.parse_args())
```

```sh
$ python testarg.py 1
usage: testarg.py [-h] input [input ...] output [output ...]
testarg.py: error: the following arguments are required: output

$ python testarg.py 1 2
Namespace(inputs=['1'], outputs=['2'])

$ python testarg.py 1 2 3 4
Namespace(inputs=['1', '2', '3'], outputs=['4'])
```

I want

```
Namespace(inputs=['1', '2'], outputs=['3', '4'])
```

Comment: I think it doesn't have function for this and it can be much simpler to use `-i` and `-o`

Comment: How do the inputs and outputs work? I'm thinking it might make more sense to pair them up, like `testarg.py input output [--io input output] ...`. That would let you use `nargs=2` to validate the numbers for you.

Comment: `input output [input output]...` is another approach that would be significantly less work to parse (just have argparse read _one_ list, then check that it has an even number of items and report it as a usage error otherwise -- something there's a convenient method for).

Comment: Thank you, pairs of `input output [input output]...` is perhaps an easier way, I didn't think about it!

Answer (score 2):

The [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/) library can do this, it supports callback functions that can modify argument values.

```py
import click


def split_args(context, param, value):
    num_args = len(value)
    if num_args % 2:
        raise click.BadParameter(
            f"Must provide an even number of arguments, got {num_args} arguments"
        )
    midpoint = num_args // 2
    return value[:midpoint], value[midpoint:]


@click.command()
@click.argument("args", callback=split_args, nargs=-1)
def io(args):
    inputs, outputs = args
    print("inputs: ", inputs)
    print("outputs: ", outputs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    io()
```

```
$ python3 testarg.py 1 2 3 4
inputs:  ('1', '2')
outputs:  ('3', '4')
```

Answer (score 1):

The `nargs` are modelled on (and even use) the `regex` wildcard quantifiers

In this case:

```
Namespace(inputs=['1', '2', '3'], outputs=['4'])
```

one value has been allocated to `outputs` (because it is "one-or-more"), and the rest, the "more" goes to `inputs`.

Now if you could accept

```
python prog.py --inputs 1 2 --outputs 3 4
```

the '+' would work as expected.

But with variable length positionals (or optional followed by positional), there's no way to tell it where the first list ends and second starts.

Of course if you like the `argparse` help, you could adjust the lists balance after parsing - e.g move the '3' to the other list.  Nothing wrong with tweaking the parsed values.  You won't get extra "good boy" points for doing everything in the parser itself.